# Rewriterule after 3 or 4 characters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My URLs are like this:

```
www.example.com/1234-title-of-an-event/whatever/
```

I need to take everything after the `"1234-"` (but it could be a 3 digit number as well, like "123-") and before the slash "/whatever" in order to redirect as:

```
www.example.com/title-of-an-event/
```

I am trying with the following rule (as the very last rule), but it doesn't seem to work and I only get a `500 Internal Server Error` .

```
RewriteRule ^\/([0-9]{3,4})-(.*)\/(.*) https://www.example.com/$2 [R=301, L]
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^\/([0-9]{3,4})-(.*)\/(.*) https://www.example.com/$2 [R=301, L]
> ```

The 500 error is most probably caused by the *space* in the flags argument. It should be `[R=301,L]` (no space). However, this directive won't do anything in `.htaccess`, because of the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. In a directory context (ie. `.htaccess`), the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* excludes the directory-prefix, which notably ends in a slash, so the URL-path that is matched never starts with a slash. (You would need to match the slash prefix in a server/vhost context.)

This also should probably not be the "very last rule" if you have other mod_rewrite directives - there could be a conflict (without seeing your entire file).

There is no need to escape slashes in the the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. Slashes carry no special meaning here, since *spaces* are effectively used as regex delimiters in Apache config files.

I would also modify your regex to match everything *except* a slash (ie. `[^/]+`), instead of *everything*, since your regex (capturing subpattern) would match `title-of-an-event/whatever` in your example URL, not `title-of-an-event`, as intended. Since regex is *greedy* by default.

So, try the following instead, near the *top* of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^\d{3,4}-([^/]+) /$1 [R=302,L]
```

This matches `/1234-title-of-an-event` and discards everything else, returning `title-of-an-event` in the `$1` backreference. (Is the trailing `/<whatever>/` required in order to make a successful match?)

`\d` is simply shorthand for `[0-9]`.

There is no need to have capturing sub-patterns in the regex if the backreferences are not being used.

There is no need to include the absolute URL in the *substitution* unless you have multiple domains or are canonicalising the scheme/hostname in the redirected response.

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect - only change to a 301 (permanent) redirect - if that is the intention - once you have confirmed that this works OK, to avoid caching issues. You will need to ensure that your browser cache is cleared before testing.